# Failed to parse as type `uint256`: a character is not in the range 0-9

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-debugging, foundry

I am following Patrick Collins [Smart Contract Lottery development](https://github.com/Cyfrin/foundry-smart-contract-lottery-f23) and trying to run the deploy script test net ( **sepolia** )  but I am getting this error

**Error**:

`` Failed to parse as type `uint256`: a character is not in the range 0-9 ``

**Snapshot**:

[image]

The function which is called during deployment to **Sepolia**:

```
function getSepoliaEthConfig() public view returns (NetworkConfig memory sepoliaNetworkConfig) {
    sepoliaNetworkConfig = NetworkConfig({
        subscriptionId: 5613, // If left as 0, our scripts will create one!
        gasLane: 0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c,
        automationUpdateInterval: 30, // 30 seconds
        raffleEntranceFee: 0.01 ether,
        callbackGasLimit: 500000, // 500,000 gas
        vrfCoordinatorV2: 0x8103B0A8A00be2DDC778e6e7eaa21791Cd364625,
        link: 0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789,
        deployerKey: vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting the value from hexadecimal to decimal format

```
cast --to-dec 0x1234567890ABcdeF
```

When working with Makefile you may get same error:

```
Failed to parse 4d5ef9****************************a38d7 as type uint256: a character is not in the range 0-9
```

For such case, add `0x` to the PK in the .env file

Comment: What do you mean `from hexa to dec`? I have configured the private key in .env and this line is reading that `deployerKey: vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY")` but i can't resolve the erorr.

Comment: wait a minute, @Alex it did work when i casted my PK to decimal and passed it in the function but what is going on :D can you please elaborate a little? TIA

Comment: In this case, delete the first characters '0x'
My .env entry looks like this: 
PRIVATE_KEY="9b7a..........................................................f9"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do we have any function or method which can directly cast this line PK to dec? ```vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY")``` 

Also I still didn't got when you mentioned `delete characters '0x'` bcz my PK don't have 0x at start.